# Laravel doesn't let me use the Mapbox example

Tags: laravel, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, laravel-6

Why does Laravel blade strip out scripts? I have been trying to show a map like in their embed examples...

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken ....
```

I can only see a link and a div, but no script and no style tag.

Although it is in the view-file, Blade removes it from the rendered page.

I get some console warnings about it not being "proper" way to include. Can this be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this code between the scripts?

```
@stack ('before-scripts')
  <script>
    ...
  </script>
@stack ('after-scripts')
```

Comment: That at least partway works and waiting for jquery/dom load got it working. What about an after-page-scripts area?